# web.config transforms not being applied on either publish or build installation package

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

Today I started playing with the `web.config` transforms in VS 2010. To begin with, I attempted the same hello world example that features in a lot of the blog posts on this topic - updating a connection string.

I created the minimal example shown below (and similar to the one found in [this blog](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html)). The problem is that whenever I do a right-click -> "Publish", or a right-click -> "Build Deployment Package" on the .csproj file, I'm not getting the correct output. Rather than a transformed web.config, I'm getting ***no*** web.config, and instead the two transform files are included.

What am I doing wrong? Any help gratefully received!

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
    connectionString="server=(local); initial catalog=myDB; 
    user=xxxx;password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Web.debug.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString"
      connectionString="server=DebugServer; initial catalog=myDB; 
      user=xxxx;password=xxxx"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
      xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Web.release.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString"
      connectionString="server=ReleaseServer; initial catalog=myDB; 
      user=xxxx;password=xxxx"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
      xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Inevitably with these things, the answer was actually staring me in the face. The presence of `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"` in the `<configuration>` node of web.config meant that my transforms weren't matching. Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: Are there side-effects in removing the xml namespace attribute? I get the same issues as you did and would like to adopt the same fix-strategy as you did, but just curious as to whether it'll break an already-flakey legacy .NET 2.0 website....

Comment: I have the same issue, but my configuration node in web.config doesn't have a namespace defined

Comment: @SpaceBison - According to [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/432077), the namespace is unnecessary. In fact, removing it fixes intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

In your web.release.config and web.debug.config files add the same namespace to your transform, ala

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and the fix was because I had Solution Configurations set up for my environments, but I had never created project configurations that align to solution configurations.

To Check:

1. Under "Build" --> "Solution Configuration"
2. Change your "Active
   solution configuration", and make sure your project configurations
   line up according to the config files you've named.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked this:

(1) menu Build - Configuration Manager

(2) pick active solution in my case Publish and configure it properly (I had there selected Debug hence no transformations from Publish were applied)